# Pre-Commit - How to Get User Roles

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

Hi im trying to validate the user permission on pre-commit. How can i get the user Roles on pre-commit?
Please Help!

Comment: There is no thing like "user roles" in subversion: You have users, groups of users and permissions(read, read/write or nothing)..
What do you want to accomplish?